# moving ruby script to cron absolute path issue

Tags: ruby, tree

I wrote following little script to give me json of the directory tree. It accepts 1 argument which is the working directory.

```
#!/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby

require 'json'

@topDir = ARGV[0]
@topEntries = Dir.glob("#{@topDir}/*").sort
@tree = {}

@topEntries.each do |dir|
 if File.directory?(dir) 
  @tree[dir] = []
  @subEntries = Dir.glob("#{dir}/*").sort
  @subEntries.each do |file|
   @tree[dir].push(file)
  end
 end
end

puts @tree.to_json
```

File structure looks like this:

```
/media/storage/topDir
/media/storage/topDir/subdir
/media/storage/topDir/subdir/sub.file
```

Ruby script lives inside topDir.

If I'm inside topDir and run my script like this:

```
./myscript.rb subdir > manifesto.json
```

It generates json with relative paths. Which is what I want.

Problem is that I've to move my script to cron.

I tried:

```
 @hourly /media/storage/topDir/myscript.rb subdir > /media/storage/topDir/manifesto.json
```

But this gave me empty {} data.

I tried:

```
@hourly /media/storage/topDir/myscript.rb /media/storage/topDir/subdir > /media/storage/topDir/manifesto.json
```

This gave me correct tree, but with absolute paths.

Now my question is, how do I run it via cron and retain relative paths?

I imagine I could simply do this string manipulation inside ruby script, and substract working directory, but is there a better way? Am I doing something wrong with the cron?

What is correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@hourly cd /media/store/topDir && ./myscript.rb subdir > manifesto.json
```